# Domain Model and related data (anemic domain model)

Tags: c#, architecture, asp.net-core, domain-driven-design, entity-framework-core

I'm currently working with ASP .NET Core 1.0 using Entity Framework Core. I have some complex calculations with data from the database and I'm not sure how to build a proper architecture using Dependency Injection *without* building an anemic domain model (http://www.martinfowler.com/bliki/AnemicDomainModel.html)

**(Simplified) Example:**

I have the following entities:

```
public class Project {
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}        
}

public class TimeEntry
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public DateTime Date {get;set;}
    public int DurationMinutes {get;set;}
    public int ProjectId {get;set;}
    public Project Project {get;set;}        
}

public class Employee {
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public List<TimeEntry> TimeEntries {get;set;}
}
```

I want to do some complex calculations to calculate a monthly TimeSheet. Because I can not access the database within the Employee entity I calculate the TimeSheet in a `EmployeeService`.

```
public class EmployeeService {
    private DbContext _db;
    public EmployeeService(DbContext db) {
        _db = db;
    }

    public List<CalculatedMonth> GetMonthlyTimeSheet(int employeeId) {
        var employee = _db.Employee.Include(x=>x.TimeEntry).ThenInclude(x=>x.Project).Single();
        var result = new List<CalculatedMonth>();

        //complex calculation using TimeEntries etc here

        return result;
    }
}
```

If I want to get the TimeSheet I need to inject the EmployeeService and call `GetMonthlyTimeSheet`.

So - I end up with a lot of GetThis() and GetThat() methods inside my service although this methods would perfectly fit into the `Employee` class itself.

What I want to achieve is something like:

```
public class Employee {
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public List<TimeEntry> TimeEntries {get;set;}

    public List<CalculatedMonth> GetMonthlyTimeSheet() {            
        var result = new List<CalculatedMonth>();

        //complex calculation using TimeEntries etc here

        return result;
    }
}

public IActionResult GetTimeSheets(int employeeId) {
    var employee = _employeeRepository.Get(employeeId);
    return employee.GetTimeSheets();
}
```

...but for that I need to make sure that the list of TimeEntries is populated from the database (EF Core does not support lazy loading). I do not want to *.Include(x=>y)* everything on every request because sometimes I just need the employee's name without the timeentries and it would affect the performance of the application.

Can anyone point me in a direction how to architect this properly?

**Edit:**
One possibility (from the comments of the first answer) would be:

```
public class Employee {
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public List<TimeEntry> TimeEntries {get;set;}

    public List<CalculatedMonth> GetMonthlyTimeSheet() { 
        if (TimeEntries == null)
          throw new PleaseIncludePropertyException(nameof(TimeEntries));

        var result = new List<CalculatedMonth>();

        //complex calculation using TimeEntries etc here

        return result;
    }
}

public class EmployeeService {
    private DbContext _db;
    public EmployeeService(DbContext db) {
        _db = db;
    }

    public Employee GetEmployeeWithoutData(int employeeId) {
        return _db.Employee.Single();
    }

    public Employee GetEmployeeWithData(int employeeId) {
        return _db.Employee.Include(x=>x.TimeEntry).ThenInclude(x=>x.Project).Single();
    }
}

public IActionResult GetTimeSheets(int employeeId) {
    var employee = _employeeService.GetEmployeeWithData(employeeId);
    return employee.GetTimeSheets();
}
```

Comment: The first step to avoid going into the Anemic domain model is to make your setters `private` and create proper constructors of the objects, with parameter validation. Also, when working with EF you will need a minimum of a `protected` constructor, if your `public` constructors are not parameter-less, as I suggest.

Comment: I think it's work considering how you might unit test your model. Making the code testable is often, IMHO, an excellent way of teasing-out design issues and their solutions. For example, are you happy that you'd be able to test (unit or integration) your `EmployeeService` given the design above?

Comment: @Jetro223 as you presented it, your model **is** anemic, whether you want it or not.

Answer (score 3):

Do not try to solve querying problems with your aggregates. Your aggregates are meant to **process commands and protect invariants**. They form a consistency boundary around a set of data.

Is the `Employee` object responsible for protecting the integrity of an employee's timesheet? If it doesn't then this data doesn't belong into the `Employee` class.

Lazy-loading may be fine for CRUD models, but is usually considered an anti-pattern when we design aggregates because those should be as small and cohesive as possible.

Are you taking business decisions based on the calculated result from timesheets? Is there any invariants to protect? Does it matter if the decision was made on stale timesheet data? If the answer to these questions is **no** then your calculation is really nothing more than a query.

Placing queries in service objects is fine. These service objects may even live outside the domain model (e.g. in the application layer), but there is no strict rule to follow. Also, you may choose to load a few aggregates in order to access the required data to process the calculations, but it's usually better to go directly in the database. This allows a better separation between your reads & writes (CQRS).

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly you can use a trick with injecting a service into your entities that helps it do the job, e.g.:

```
public class Employee()
{
    public object GetTimeSheets(ICalculatorHelper helper)
    {
    }
}
```

Then in your service that holds the employees you would obtain it in the constructor and pass to the employee class for calculations. This service can be a Facade e.g. for getting all the data and perform initialization or whatever you really need.

As for the TimeEntries, you can get them using a function like this:

```
private GetTimeEntries(ICalculationHelper helper)
{
   if (_entries == null)
   {
       _entries = helper.GetTimeEntries();
   }
   return _entries;
}
```

It depends of course on you strategy of caching and so on if this pattern fits you.

Personally I find it rather easy to work with anemic classes and have a lot of the business logic in services. I do put some in the objects, like e.g. calculating FullName out of FirstName and LastName. Usually stuff that does not involve other services. Though it's a matter of preference.

Comment: And how is that `ICalculatorHelper` helping here? His problem is that the data may or may not be loaded into the object.

Comment: @HristoYankov: it helps in so far that he do not has to worry about how to fetch the data, that's task of the `ICalculatorHelper` (or some other named service) and he can keep the logic for the calculation either within the model (if its specific tot he model) or in the calculator helper if its out of the scope of the given model

Comment: This is just wrong. The data is already supposed to be in the class. The class should not receive the data twice - once from a property, and another time from some parameter injected dependency.

Comment: So let me summarize: you suggest that the class receives some dependencies on each method, which helps it load its properties? I can easily see this spinning out of control and turning into a full-blown spaghetti code.

Comment: Thanks - but for that the ICalculatorHelper would have to have a dependency on the DbContext for loading the related data. This would help to build smaller, specialized classes instead of a giant EmployeeService. But then I just could inject the DbContext (in every method :-/) in the method and load the related data from there.

Comment: You should just implement your repository in a way to give you the entire set, for every request, and hope that they implement the Lazy Loading soon. A little poorer performance might be better than very badly written code, as per the above suggestion! https://jessedotnet.com/2016/02/27/entity-framework-7-lazy-loading-and-eager-loading/

Comment: @HristoYankov That's not an option and would lead to significant slower response times (my example only shows a small subset of related properties)

Comment: Not true, you can implement additional `get`-only properties on your DbContext which give you a loaded or not object. E.g. `Employees` and `EmployeesWithTimeSheets`. The latter will have `.Include`s. Then use whatever property you need from your repo, in your specific case and invoke its methods safely. Naturally, throw exceptions in your `Employee` class if the data is not loaded.

Comment: Maybe an option, but for that the caller must know from the outside which properties need to be populated that it's possible to call a method on an entity and this feels a little "the wrong way around"

Comment: Your caller would be a Unit of Work (or Service), which does: 1. Load the data from the repo and 2. Call a method on the data. So, he would know about the coupling between the appropriate DbContext set and the method that will be called. Your objects remain correctly written, you don't know about external dependencies and so on. Then some day Lazy Loading is enabled on EF Core and you stop worrying about the coupling, while your code remains correctly written instead of sacrificed.

Comment: @HristoYankov You're right - much better than the current "service does everything". Maybe with some PleaseIncludePropertyXYZIfYouWantToCallThisMethodException() ;-)

Comment: One of the key principles of DDD is that the domain drives the design. Do you have concepts like `EmployeeService` and `CalculatorHelpers` in your business domain? Do employees do their own calculations? Using the 'ubiquitous language' of your business domain in your code will not only help to create more self-documenting code but it will also create clearer responsibility boundaries. I think this will help you create a more 'full-blooded' model.